# Possible combinations of records in sql server based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Input is like below:

```
c1    c2      req         qty
1      A1     234         34
1      A1     547         45
1      A1     12P7        0.25
1      A1     12P8        0.25
1      A1     12P9        0.25
```

My Output should be like below:(Need a combinations of records with 'P' as values for every c1,c2
)

```
c1    c2      c3    req         qty
1      A1      1    234         34
1      A1      1    547         45
1      A1      1    12P7        0.75

1      A1      2    234         34
1      A1      2    547         45
1      A1      2    12P8        0.75

1      A1      3    234         34
1      A1      3    547         45
1      A1      3    12P7        0.375
1      A1      3    12P8        0.375

1      A1      4    234         34
1      A1      4    547         45
1      A1      4    12P7        0.375
1      A1      4    12P9        0.375

1      A1      5    234         34
1      A1      5    547         45
1      A1      5    12P8        0.375
1      A1      5    12P9        0.375
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to enumerate the difference conditions.  One trick is allocating `req`.  This is handled by calculating the total and dividing by the number of rows in the group:

```
select t.c1, t.c2, v.c3, t.req,
       (case when t.req like '12%'
             then (qty_total /
                   sum(case when t.req like '12%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by v.c3)
                  )
             else qty
        end)
from (select t.*, sum(case when req like '12%' then qty end) over () as qty_total
      from t 
     ) t cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(c3)
where t.req not like '12%' or
      (v.c3 = 1 and t.req in ('12P7') or
       v.c3 = 2 and t.req in ('12P8') or
       v.c3 = 3 and t.req in ('12P7', '12P8') or
       v.c3 = 4 and t.req in ('12P7', '12P9') or
       v.c3 = 5 and t.req in ('12P8', '12P9') 
      )
order by c3, c1, c2;
```

If your database doesn't support this exact syntax, it supports something similar.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9e7b6530a63576ad00704eda48f1128) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the above code. Need small correction, you have hard coded the t.req columns but need to generate those combinations dynamically. For Ex: what if there are 12P10,12P11,12P12,12P13....

Comment: @YMK . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  In fact, it has a db<>fiddle illustrating that the answer works.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.